# Rails 5: API params combine two values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 5 API application I have a product with the attributes uid and version among other attributes:
With just params :uid it worked fine:

api/v1/products_controller.rb

```
    def show
      @product = Spree::Product.where(metauid: params[:metauid])
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: @product }
      end
    end
```

routes:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :products, param: :uid
  end
end
```

But Now I haveto add a new parameter :version additional to the existing uid in the show/delete/create - Requests so that it looks like uid_v{versionnumber} eg. foo_v1

What I tried so far:

routes:

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :products, path: '/:uid/:version', only: [:show, :update, :create, :destroy] # index should be available without uid&version param
    end
  end
```

api/v1/products_controller.rb

```
    def show
      uid = params
      @product = Spree::Product.where(uid: params[:uid]).where(version: params[:version])
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: @product }
      end
    end
```

But I'm getting an empty array back instead of the product even though the record shows up in my Rails console.

UPDATE:

```
bundle exec rails routes shows:
                      GET                       /api/v1/products(.:format)                                                    spree/api/v1/products#index {:format=>"json"}
                      POST                      /api/v1/products(.:format)                                                    spree/api/v1/products#create {:format=>"json"}
    new_api_v1_product GET                       /api/v1/products/new(.:format)                                                spree/api/v1/products#new {:format=>"json"}
  edit_api_v1_product GET                       /api/v1/products/:id/edit(.:format)                                           spree/api/v1/products#edit {:format=>"json"}
                      GET                       /api/v1/products/:id(.:format)                                                spree/api/v1/products#show {:format=>"json"}
                      PATCH                     /api/v1/products/:id(.:format)                                                spree/api/v1/products#update {:format=>"json"}
                      PUT                       /api/v1/products/:id(.:format)                                                spree/api/v1/products#update {:format=>"json"}
                      DELETE                    /api/v1/products/:id(.:format)                                                spree/api/v1/products#destroy {:format=>"json"}
  next_api_v1_checkout PUT                       /api/v1/checkouts/:id/next(.:format)                                          spree/api/v1/checkouts#next {:format=>"json"}
```

Comment: Could you include the output of the product-relevant part of `rails routes -g product`?

Comment: I added the relevant routes using bundle exec rails routes

Comment: The routes you listed, which router example is that for?